# Flutter SDK: Files Deleted Automatically (e.g., dart.exe), Errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk, filesystems

I've encountered a persistent issue with my Flutter development environment where essential files from the Flutter SDK, such as dart.exe, are being deleted automatically without any apparent reason or intervention from my side. This deletion has caused disruptions to my workflow and led to errors within Android Studio.

Upon opening Android Studio, I received the error message:
"The Flutter device daemon cannot be started. Please check your configuration and restart the IDE. You may need to increase the maximum number of file handles available globally."

Additionally, when attempting to run `flutter doctor` from the command line, I received the following error:

> `"C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe"` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I've investigated potential causes such as malware, disk errors, and permissions, but haven't identified the root cause of these file deletions and associated errors. Despite reinstalling the Flutter SDK multiple times, the problem persists.

**-Reviewed Permissions:** I verified the permissions and ownership settings of the Flutter SDK files and directories to ensure they were correct.

**-Reinstalled SDK:** I reinstalled the Flutter SDK multiple times to attempt to restore the missing files and resolve the issue.